# Difference between socket libraries

Tags: sockets, http

I have a script that I can configure to either use a socket library or use libcurl. I am using http access methods. When I use the socket library each request takes much longer as compared to when I switch to libcurl. Both of them work though.

I am curious to understand the difference. Is there a way I can look at the raw request and response for the network communication so I can investigate this? Something like what the browser shows for each page request would be ideal.

I am on a windows system. But if there is a software that can work on both windows and linux that would be great. Any help on how I can dig into this would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Libraries for which language? C?

Comment: If you run wireshark you can see what data is being sent and received, and when.

Comment: Yep, wireshark is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I will try out wireshark.